# Calling a mysql column using template literals node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to call a field from mysql within my node js file using template literals but am unable to obtain the value. Please take a look at my post.controller.js file below where is says  message: `Post ${body.post_id} was successfully created` where post_id is a field within my mysql database.

//The following code is in post.service.js file

```
const pool = require("../../config/database");

module.exports = {

  //Create new post
  createPost: (data, callBack) =>{
    pool.query(
      `insert into posts(userhandle, post_body)
              values(?,?)`,
    [
      data.userhandle,
      data.post_body
    ],
    (error, results, fields) =>{
      if(error){
        return callBack(error);
      }
      return callBack(null, results);
    }
    );
  }
}
```

//The following code is in post.controller.js file

```
const {
  createPost,
} = require("./post.service");


module.exports = {

  //Controller for creating new post
  createPost: (req, res) =>{
    const body = req.body;
    createPost(body, (err, results) => {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          success:0,
          message:"Error. Unable to create post"
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: 1,
        message: `Post ${body.post_id} was successfully created`,
        data: results

      });
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't recognize this template syntax used in the query in the service. Can you explain that?

Comment: So where is says message: `Post ${body.post_id} was successfully created` I am trying to input the post id once it is successfully created. I want the post_id to be pulled from mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing post_id is a PK auto incremented, if that so try `results.post_id`, since this is an object retuned from callback.
If this won't work do the `console.log(results)` and see if post_id is in it.

Comment: @ForestProgramming